# Magento 2 upgrade killed process

Tags: upgrade, composer, magento-upgrade, magento2.3.2

I want to upgrade Magento 2.1.7 to Magento 2.3.2 and I follow below commands

```
sudo composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.3.2 --no-update
sudo composer require --dev phpunit/phpunit:~6.2.0 friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer:~2.10.1 lusitanian/oauth:~0.8.10 pdepend/pdepend:2.5.2 sebastian/phpcpd:~3.0.0 squizlabs/php_codesniffer:3.2.2 --no-update
sudo composer remove --dev sjparkinson/static-review fabpot/php-cs-fixer --no-update
sudo composer update
```

But **sudo composer update command killed.**

please see below image.
[image]

Please help me on how to upgrade from 2.1.7 to 2.3.2.

Comment: Same task performing someone then its happens

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you get "Killed" message when there is not enough resources to complete the task

Comment: Thanks for the answer. what to do next step to resolve issue and update magento from 2.1.7 to 2.3.2?

Comment: Make sure that you PHP is configured to have at least 2GB or Unlimited (-1) RAM as maximum memory. Also with my experience with Magento version upgrades, I learnt that is is a good idea to replace you composer.json with default one for version you upgrade from and then after upgrade reinstall any extensions you need via composer which support your new Magento version